# Не работает pyinstaller Python 3.9

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.9

Здраствуйте дорогие пользователи, установил pyinstaller вроде всё прошло нормально
Но при попытке скомпилировать файл .py, командная строка выдаёт ошибку мол такой команды нету что делать просто только нача изучать питон и никак не знаю как исправить.

Comment: добавьте полный текст ошибки в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите при установке галочку "add to PATH"

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1273106/edit)